# connect to C# server on EC2 (AWS)

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, networking, amazon-ec2, tcp

I'm trying to connect to a C# TCP server I'm running on EC2.
But my server's not responding. This is the code that running on the EC2:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    TcpListener serverSocket = new TcpListener(8888);
    TcpClient clientSocket = default(TcpClient);
    serverSocket.Start();
    clientSocket = serverSocket.AcceptTcpClient();
    Console.WriteLine("new client connected");
}
```

And them from my own PC I'm trying to run this code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    TcpClient clientSocket = new TcpClient();
    clientSocket.Connect("35.163.41.3", 8888);
    Console.WriteLine("you connected to the server!");
}
```

This is the security group of my EC2:

[image: Security group]

What could the problem be?

Comment: Do your code work locally?

Comment: @shadowfox476 When I'm running the server and client on my local PC with IP `127.0.0.1` it's working and also if i'm running the server and the client in the EC2 with IP `127.0.0.1` it's working but not with IP `35.163.41.3`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It could be a number of things.  First thing I would check is Windows Firewall on the server to make sure that it is allowing that port.

Comment: Also -- as mentioned above I would check to see if it responded on localhost on the server using telnet or some other client.

Comment: Thank you! that was the problem. when I disabled the firewall by going to: `Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Windows Firewall` > `Turn Windows Firewall on or off` it worked!. I know it's not the bast idea to disable your firewall but if you want to get in the details you can allow only some ports and IP